# Have detected memory leak but unable to undersatand the exact cause as hash map entry is confusing?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

I am using eclipse MAT to analyse heap dump of my application. This is showing a class as leak suspect. one instance variable is declared as static hash map which is responsible for thousands of entries per hour. In the dominator tree view of the suspected class some times the value for entry is found like

```
hashmap$entry->classname->value
```

but most of the time it's like

```
hashmap$entry->hashmap$entry->....->classname->value
```

In this case the uppermost `hash$mapp` entry is showing 20% consumption.The lower lesser and so on. The `hashmap$entry` which is associated with the class name has lesser consumption and the upper and middle `hashmap$entry` can't be expanded.

I am confused what it mean? Could any one please explain it or suggest any document which can explain these things ?Thanks in Advance

Comment: jmat is very hard to read IMHO. I would suggest using VisualVM or a commercial profiler to profile your memory.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Did you mean `jhat`?

Answer (score 0):

Java HashMap class has an internal data structure Entry. If you add an entry to your map (via put()) it will create a Entry holding your key/value pair.

If a second key is added having the same hash, the Entry structure is chained. I guess the same entries are added over and over again but new objects are created for the key resulting in massive chaining.

Do you see what Object types are in the map key & value?

Comment: Thanks a lot. the object types in the map are key is an interface and value is class in which the hashmap is declared. I am further analysing it and ask you if i would get stuck. Thanking you again.

Comment: I would suggest to check how the equals method is defined in the key class.